# PHP forked processes accept connections

Tags: php, sockets, fork

I wanted to know if I forked a processes after I bonded the IP and port of the server. Will the fork be able to accept the connection. To extend on that if I have 10 forks running all trying to accept is there a chance that more then 1 could accept the same connection or is there some locking on that?

A few days ago I felt like writing writing a http server in php. So it can handle more then one connection at a time. The master processes accepted the connection reads the data in and passes it to a thread via a unix socket. So far on my laptop i can get 1000 connections a second on a little page that gives the current date and time. One of the bottle necks is the master processes. Originally i would have loved to gotten the file descriptors of the connections and passed those to the sockets and have them read the data in then processes it.

Comment: I think you have to put on the brakes for a moment. You mention a lot of things without explaining what you mean by them. Take it one thing at a time, and explain what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I added to the question if you want me to make the github project public let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the forked children will be able to accept new connections on the same (inherited) listening socket.

Assuming you're using a blocking `socket_accept()` in all your child processes, you shouldn't experience any performance issues even if it ramps up to 100 processes; the operating system will wake up one child process to handle the connection.

It should be mentioned that it's good practice to benchmark it, using `ab` or similar load generator tools.

Comment: I added more to the question and i can make the repo on github public if needed, I have it set with a master processes right now. I am trying to allow the children to handle more work and not get bottle necked by the master the number i use for testing is currently 10 children i would like to make it 100 at some point if not more.